# Does high definition videos play smoothly on Samsung N150 Plus?

Tags: graphics, video, samsung

I have a Samsung N-150 plus net-book, and I have always had difficulties in watching movies on it. I thought it's due to Windows 7 starter, so I changed my OS to Windows XP.

Although its been running quite smoother after then, but in high definition movies it plays them like slow motion and sometimes the movie's sound and display are not matched together.

I read in Yahoo answer that Ubuntu may help me in this field, and I came here to ask you if its helpful to install Ubuntu on my net-book?

Answer (score 2):

I found this question somewhat funny, since your computer has only 1024x600 display.

Nevertheless, Samsung N-150 has an Intel Atom N455 1.66 GHz and GMS 3150 graphics card, which is simply not enough to flawlessly play high definition movies. Perhaps it could handle some 720p movies depending on the used coded, but definitely not 1080p. Changing OS will not help, since it's the hardware that is not powerful enough.

There was a discussion about this CPU and HD movies, [here](http://forum.notebookreview.com/acer/587450-will-netbook-able-play-hd-video.html).
And another link related to what Atom CPU's could handle particular HD content, [here](http://www.tlbhd.com/can-i-play-hd-content-on-a-netbook-10286/).